# How to flush output after each `echo` call?

Tags: php, apache, echo, flush

I have a php script that only produces logs to the client.
When I echo something, I want it to be transferred to client on-the-fly.
(Because while the script is processing, the page is blank)
I had already played around with `ob_start()` and `ob_flush()`, but they didn't work.

What's the best solution?

PS: it is a little dirty to put a flush at the end of the `echo` call...

EDIT: Neither the Answers worked, PHP or Apache Fault?

Comment: On the fly? You mean echo as it's being produced? Because output buffering functions like ob_start are there to do the exact opposite.

Comment: @Manos Dilaverakis - I mean, when i do an echo, i wan't it to be directly transfered to the client, for now, the page is loading, and only at the end of the script, it transfer all at once. Cat it be  apache is fault?

Comment: That is expected behaviour - output is sent once the script stops executing, unless you specify otherwise. Depending on how your application is designed, you may be able to flush the buffer at certain points in execution (for example when a class is instantiated or a given view function which is often called is run).

Answer (score 45, accepted):

**Edit:**

I was reading the comments on the manual page and came across [a bug](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=23877) that states that `ob_implicit_flush` *does not work* and the following is a workaround for it:

```
ob_end_flush();

# CODE THAT NEEDS IMMEDIATE FLUSHING

ob_start();
```

If this does not work then what may even be happening is that the client does not receive the packet from the server until the server has built up enough characters to send what it considers a packet worth sending.

---

**Old Answer:**

You could use [`ob_implicit_flush`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-implicit-flush.php) which will tell output buffering to turn off buffering for a while:

```
ob_implicit_flush(true);

# CODE THAT NEEDS IMMEDIATE FLUSHING

ob_implicit_flush(false);
```

Comment: Yes, definitely I'm looking for something like that (+1), but it didn't worked :s  
Can it be Apache's fault?

Comment: These two comments to that function may help: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-implicit-flush.php#35072
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-implicit-flush.php#33778

Comment: If i stop the flush `ob_end_flush()`, my program skips the important step (don't know why ;s)
I've added the line `flush` on my Class `DebugEcho` function, and it didn't workedtoo, besides, it's a little bad and time consuming doing a flush on the cache every `echo` call.

Comment: ob_end_flush will clear the buffer and stop output buffering completely, so don't use that until you're sure that you don't want to buffer anymore content!

Comment: You still need to `flush()` after each line of output as it is not guaranteed to be sent to the client immediately.

Comment: You said that the server may not send the data until it has enough data collected. I wonder how to configure this size.

Comment: @amphetamachine thanks! is it possible to flush on top of the previously flushed contents?

Comment: The above are rather old and not working. The 2018 version below is the only one working in 2018

Comment: **Code doesn't work.** tested on awardspace free hosting default settings, firefox.

Comment: The edit on this answer worked for me in 2020 combined with flush() and ob_flush().

Answer (score 74):

I've gotten the same issue and one of the posted example in the manual worked. A character set must be specified as one of the posters here already mentioned. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php#109314

```
header( 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
echo 'Begin ...<br />';
for( $i = 0 ; $i < 10 ; $i++ )
{
    echo $i . '<br />';
    ob_flush();
    flush();
    sleep(1);
}
echo 'End ...<br />';
```

Comment: I tried everything to get output-flushing working correctly. The thing that got it working in the end was "Content-type" header in your example. Thankyou fine sir!!!

Comment: Yep, solved it for me as well. Awesome. Although, I also had to enable implicit flushing, but whatever. :)

Comment: None of the examples here and other pages worked for me.Linux with Apache and php 7

Comment: I found that if the first echo is a tag, it seems to fail. Like `echo '<h1>Begin...</h1>';` as the first echo would cause the entire thing to wait until it was finished. Using the exact example here worked fine on centos, apache, and php 7.

Comment: **Code doesn't work.** tested on awardspace free hosting default settings, firefox.

Comment: Not working, tested with Firefox, Chrome, Edge, IE.

Comment: I improved this code a little by ob_flush()ing any explicit programmer induced caching first before trying to fully flush() to the browser. It is still possible for the Apache/web server to do its own caching that cannot be controlled by php code, or for the browser to cache contents before displaying it to you.

Comment: It works without the `header` and `flush`. You just need the `ob_flush`.

Answer (score 45):

So here's what I found out.

Flush would not work under Apache's mod_gzip or Nginx's gzip because, logically, it is gzipping the content, and to do that it must buffer content to gzip it. Any sort of web server gzipping would affect this. In short, at the server side we need to disable gzip and decrease the fastcgi buffer size. So:

- In php.ini:

  ```
  output_buffering = Off

  zlib.output_compression = Off
  ```
- In nginx.conf:

  ```
  gzip  off;

  proxy_buffering  off;
  ```

Also have these lines at hand, especially if you don't have access to php.ini:

```
@ini_set('zlib.output_compression',0);

@ini_set('implicit_flush',1);

@ob_end_clean();

set_time_limit(0);
```

Last, if you have it, comment the code bellow:

```
ob_start('ob_gzhandler');

ob_flush();
```

**PHP test code:**

```
ob_implicit_flush(1);

for ($i=0; $i<10; $i++) {
    echo $i;

    // this is to make the buffer achieve the minimum size in order to flush data
    echo str_repeat(' ',1024*64);

    sleep(1);
}
```

Comment: The key to the answer for me was the `//this is for the buffer achieve the minimum size in order to flush data
    echo str_repeat(' ',1024*64);`

Comment: Only this worked for me. +1 for the `str_repeat` bit, but perhaps a good idea to make it an invisible character instead of a whitespace?

Comment: So how do we disable gzip for that page only?

Comment: `echo str_repeat(' ',1024*64);` made the `flush` work. But how come I couldn't find it anywhere else? The documentation doesn't mention it either....

Comment: The minimum buffer size is the critical missing piece. thanks!

Comment: this is ultimate, god level steps to confirmed success. in "echo str_repeat(' ',1024*64);" i had to use 4096 instead of 1024 for better real time echo. cheers

Comment: This sorta works.. but having to send so many bytes **defeats the purpose**.

Answer (score 20):

For those coming in 2018:

The ONLY Solution worked for me:

```
<?php

    if (ob_get_level() == 0) ob_start();
    for ($i = 0; $i<10; $i++){

        echo "<br> Line to show.";
        echo str_pad('',4096)."\n";    

        ob_flush();
        flush();
        sleep(2);
    }

    echo "Done.";

    ob_end_flush();
?>
```

and its very important to keep de "4096" part because it seems that "fills" the buffer...

Comment: Not working great in 2020; the first 4 lines are displayed all in once after like 4 seconds, then after this, each new line is displayed one per sec.

Comment: BUT if I increase the str_pad value, it's working better! with 4096000 its displaying pretty well. It's definitly a value of content handled by the browser.

Comment: Isn't sending 4MB of text data in each step a bit overkill?

Comment: @M.i.X yes it is! but it's the only way (I know) to do this using just php... the correct way should be ajax, but if you want use just php I don't know a better way

Comment: I use 4096 but did not work, change to 1024*64 working fine. I don't know why.

Comment: This worked for me without the sleep(2); line.

Comment: You can also change the `output_buffering = 4096` setting in `php.ini` to some lower value to avoid `str_pad`'ding to 4096.

Comment: After a million tries, this is the ONLY code that worked for me with FastCGI. But using 4096 didn't work. I had to use `str_pad('',1024*64);`

Answer (score 12):

Flushing seemingly failing to work is a side effect of automatic character set detection.

The browser will not display anything until it knows the character set to display it in, and if you don't specify the character set, it need tries to guess it. The problem being that it can't make a good guess without enough data, which is why browsers seem to have this 1024 byte (or similar) buffer they need filled before displaying anything.

The solution is therefore to make sure the browser doesn't have to guess the character set.

If you're sending text, add a '; charset=utf-8' to its content type, and if it's HTML, add the character set to the appropriate meta tag.

Comment: **Doesn't work.** tested on awardspace free hosting default settings, firefox.

Answer (score 9):

what you want is the [flush](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php) method.
example:

```
echo "log to client";
 flush();
```

Comment: @CuSS Regardless, this is the only way to satisfy the functionality that you want

Comment: what's dirty about it? That's what flush() was designed to do, and it gets the job done.

Comment: `ini_set('implicit_flush', true)` will basically emulate a flush() after ever output block, and it can get set pretty much anywhere (php.ini, .htaccess, per-script, etc...)

Comment: **Code doesn't work.** tested on awardspace free hosting default settings, firefox.

Answer (score 5):

Why not make a function to echo, like this:

```
function fecho($string) {
 echo $string;
 ob_flush();
}
```

Comment: Better that @GSto Answer, but I'm searching for something like @amphetamachine Answer... You will get +1 ;)

Comment: **Code doesn't work.** tested on awardspace free hosting default settings, firefox.

Answer (score 5):

One thing that is not often mentionned is gzip compression that keeps turned ON because of details in various hosting environments.

Here is a modern approach, working with PHP-FPM as Fast CGI, which does not need .htaccess rewrite rule or environment variable :

In php.ini or .user.ini :

```
output_buffering = 0
zlib.output_compression = 0
implicit_flush = true
output_handler =
```

In PHP script :

```
header('Content-Encoding: none'); // Disable gzip compression
ob_end_flush(); // Stop buffer
ob_implicit_flush(1); // Implicit flush at each output command
```

See [this comment](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-implicit-flush.php#116748) on official PHP doc for ob_end_flush() need.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me, and I tried all. Thanks!

Comment: Not working great in 2020; the first 4 lines are displayed all in once after like 4 seconds, then after this, each new line is displayed one per sec

Comment: **Code doesn't work.** tested on awardspace free hosting default settings, firefox.

Answer (score 5):

```
header( 'X-Accel-Buffering: no' );
header( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );

echo 'text to display';
echo '<span style="display: none;">' . str_repeat ( ' ', 4096 ) . '</span>';
flush();
usleep( 10 );
```

Comment: Baam! Thank you so much for pointing out this X-Accel-Buffering Header!! 
After having tried nearly everything on my ionos webspace this really saved my day!!  :)

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar thing to do. Using

```
// ini_set("output_buffering", 0);  // off 
ini_set("zlib.output_compression", 0);  // off
ini_set("implicit_flush", 1);  // on
```

did make the output flushing frequent in my case.

But I had to flush the output right at a particular point(in a loop that I run), so using both

```
ob_flush();
flush();
```

together worked for me.

> I wasn't able to
>   turn off **"output_buffering"** with
>   ini_set(...), had to turn it directly
>   in php.ini, phpinfo() shows its setting
>   as "no value" when turned off, is that
>   normal? .

Comment: Yes if phpinfo() shows "no value", it means that output_buffering is set to off. Otherwise it would say like 4096

Comment: **Code doesn't work.** tested on awardspace free hosting default settings, firefox.

Answer (score 3):

The correct function to use is `flush()`.

```
<html>
<body>
<p>
Hello! I am waiting for the next message...<br />
<?php flush(); sleep(5); ?>
I am the next message!<br />
<?php flush(); sleep(5); ?>
And I am the last message. Good bye.
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Please note that there is a "problem" with IE, which only outputs the flushed content when it is at least 256 byte, so your first part of the page needs to be at least 256 byte.

Comment: Cool, didn't knew about that IE Bug... Is that any function besides `echo` and `print` that prints directly to the browser?

Comment: @CuSS: It's not a bug; it's an "undocumented feature"

Comment: **Code doesn't work.** tested on awardspace free hosting default settings, firefox.

Answer (score 3):

This works fine for me (Apache 2.4/PHP 7.0):

```
@ob_end_clean();
echo "lorem ipsum...";
flush();
sleep(5);
echo "<br>dolor...";
flush();
sleep(5);
echo "<br>sit amet";
```

Comment: **Code doesn't work.** tested on awardspace free hosting default settings, firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Anti-virus software may also be interfering with output flushing. In my case, Kaspersky Anti-Virus 2013 was holding data chunks before sending it to the browser, even though I was using an accepted solution.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, the problem come from Apache settings. Apache can be set to gzip the output.
In the file .htaccess you can add for instance :

```
SetEnv no-gzip 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
while (@ob_end_flush());      
ob_implicit_flush(true);

echo "first line visible to the browser";
echo "<br />";

sleep(5);

echo "second line visible to the browser after 5 secs";
```

Just notice that this way you're actually disabling the output buffer for your current script. I guess you can reenable it with ob_start() (i'm not sure).

Important thing is that by disabling your output buffer like above, you will not be able to redirect your php script anymore using the `header()` function, because php can sent only once per script execution http headers. 
You can however redirect using javascript. Just let your php script echo following lines when it comes to that:

```
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
        echo 'window.location.href="'.$url.'";';
        echo '</script>';
        echo '<noscript>';
        echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url='.$url.'" />';
        echo '</noscript>'; 
        exit;
```

Comment: **Code doesn't work.** tested on awardspace free hosting default settings, firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Note if you are on certain shared hosting sites like Dreamhost you can't disable PHP output buffering at all without going through different routes:

> Changing the output buffer cache If you are using PHP FastCGI, the PHP
>   functions flush(), ob_flush(), and ob_implicit_flush() will not
>   function as expected. By default, output is buffered at a higher level
>   than PHP (specifically, by the **Apache module mod_deflate** which is
>   similar in form/function to mod_gzip).
>
> If you need unbuffered output, you must either **use CGI** (instead of
>   FastCGI) or contact support to **request that mod_deflate is disabled**
>   for your site.

https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/214202188-PHP-overview

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the discussion but I read that many people are saying appending flush(); at the end of each code looks dirty, and they are right.

**Best solution** is to disable deflate, gzip and all buffering from Apache, intermediate handlers and PHP. Then in your php.ini you should have:

```
            output_buffering = Off
            zlib.output_compression = Off
            implicit_flush = Off
```

**Temporary solution** is to have this in your php.ini **IF** you can solve your problem with flush(); but you think it is dirty and ugly to put it everywhere.

```
implicit_flush = On
```

If you only put it above in your php.ini, you don't need to put flush(); in your code anymore.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code: (work for PHP7)

```
private function closeConnection()
{
    @apache_setenv('no-gzip', 1);
    @ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 0);
    @ini_set('implicit_flush', 1);

    ignore_user_abort(true);
    set_time_limit(0);

    ob_start();
    // do initial processing here
    echo json_encode(['ans' => true]);

    header('Connection: close');
    header('Content-Length: ' . ob_get_length());
    ob_end_flush();
    ob_flush();
    flush();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48914827/7485823

```
$input  = "Hello world";
echo str_pad($input,  1024*64, " ");
```

A lovely and practically sollution -  with a a catch: A lot of recundant blanks in your output.

It produces in

- Chrome + Edge: Produces a 10,005 character string ending with "…" as truncation
- Firefox: A 65540 character string (sic)

Changing `str_repeat` to `str_pad` minimizes the issue. But changing the padding character from blank " " to null "\x00" seems the reduce the problem even further.

```
$input  = "Hello world";
echo str_pad($input,  1024*64, "\x00");
```

Produces in Chrome, Edge and Firefox a 15 character string

I cannot tell where the string is truncated. But the cache on the server is filled and the output is send AND your output is not cluttered by a menace of redundant blanks.