# printing process output in realtime

Tags: php, apache

I am using PHP 5.3.4 with Apache 2.2.17 on a Windows 7 x64 system.  I would like to have my PHP page output the result of a `system` call in real-time to the user's browser. To that end, I have configured `output_buffering=Off` in php.ini and created this code:

```
<?php
ob_implicit_flush(true);
ob_end_flush();
system('ping -n 10 www.google.com');
?>
```

The result of the ping is printed in real-time, but I also get a PHP diagnostic error and callstack at the top of my page that says:

```
Notice: ob_end_flush() [ref.outcontrol]: failed to delete and flush buffer. No buffer to delete or flush in index.php on line 3
```

What do I need to do to either correct or suppress this error?

**Update**
If I change `ob_end_flush()` to `$a = 1/0;` I get a similar error and the output is realtime in all browsers. Is it something about the way the exception is printed that causes this to work?

Comment: Remove `ob_end_flush();`

Comment: If I remove it or suppress with an @, the output is no longer realtime in Chrome 16 or Firefox 10. (Though, it does work in IE9)

Comment: That's odd, but see my answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

some web *browsers* buffer the first x bytes before they start to render a page, under certain conditions.

try just outputting lots of whitespace first

Comment: Yup. This was the issue. Thank you!

Comment: I had to echo exactly 894 characters to the browser to enable real time output. Tested on Firefox 21 and IE 8.

Answer (score 3):

I have a solution that works, but it is non-performant and *icky*. I throw an exception, but hide the exception dialog.

```
<?php
    ob_implicit_flush(true);

    // Something about the way exceptions are thrown causes Firefox and Chrome 
    // to be able to display the results of the system call in real-time rather
    // than having to wait for the call to complete. So, I just hide the 
    // exception message. IE9 works with or without this.
    echo "<div style=\"display:none\">";
    $a = 1/0;
    echo "</div>";

    echo "<pre>";
    system('ping -n 5 www.google.com');
    echo "</pre>";
?>
```

To auto-scroll to the bottom of the page, I add some javascript:

```
<html><head>
<script language="javascript">
var int = self.setInterval("window.scrollBy(0,1000);", 200);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    // insert above php code here
    // stop scrolling when the execution finishes
    echo '<script language="javascript">int = window.clearInterval(int);</script>';
?>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**

@Chris's answer shows a much better solution.

```
echo '<div style="display:none">';
for ($a = 0; $a < 768; $a++)
    echo ' ';
echo '</div>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add this to flush the buffer:

```
    if (eregi("chrome",$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
       echo "<div style=\"display:none\">";
          echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
          echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";    
          echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";    
          echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
          echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
          echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
          echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
          echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
          echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
          echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
          echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
          echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
          echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
          echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
       echo "</div>";
    }
```

It has to be inside the loop. or between two output you need to show in real-time.

AND here's the shorthand trick:

add this:

```
if (eregi("chrome",$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
   echo "<div style=\"display:none\"></div>";                    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the error is pretty easy to interpret.

You call `ob_end_flush()` on line 3, but (like the error says), there is no output to flush. In essence, line 3 is useless because no output has been sent, so deleting the line will fix the error. If this is incorporated into a larger file, you might need to keep `ob_end_flush()` because some output may already have been captured.

EDIT: Since you need to flush it, either:

a: add `ob_start();` to the top of the file.

b: replace `ob_end_flush();` with `flush();`

EDIT2: Since the first didn't seem to work, this is the best I can offer: [How to echo output in real time, (before script finishes)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906816/how-to-echo-output-in-real-time-before-script-finishes)

Comment: If I remove it the output is no longer realtime in Chrome 16 or Firefox 10. (Though, it does work in IE9)

Comment: per your edit - With change A, it is not realtime in any browser. With change B it is realtime only in IE9.

Comment: @PaulH Take a look at the answer to the question I linked. Similar, and probably the same problem.

Comment: I have output buffering disabled. I know the browsers are capable of doing this because they will do it when the error is displayed. I've added linefeeds before the `system` call in various forms to no effect. `echo PHP_EOL; echo "<BR />"; echo "\r\n";`

Comment: The only other thing I can think of, is to use `ob_start()` with a custom callback function to automatically flush the output.

Answer (score 0):

ob_end_flush() flushes the php output buffer, and requires an active output buffer created with ob_start().

I think you just want to call flush() to send the data to the client.

```
<?php
ob_implicit_flush(true);
flush();
system('ping -n 10 www.google.com');
?>
```

Comment: With this code, the output is not realtime in Chrome 16 or Firefox 10. (Though this does work in IE9)

Comment: I think that the browsers (Chrome 16 and ff10) are caching the text before rendering it. I'd go with javascript+ajax, get one ping output at time and display it to the user. I'd be interested in a reliable way to force the page rendering too...

Comment: I can make it work perfectly if I'm willing to put up with an exception dialog at the top of the page. I don't think the browsers are incapable of doing this.

Comment: It may work but there is no reliable solution as far as I know. I just said that a browser may be buffering the data before rendering it. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php