# Autoscroll in bash script output called from PHP

Tags: php, html, bash

I have a PHP script which prints the output of a bash script (actually it is an expect script), which looks like this:

```
<?php

ob_implicit_flush(true);
ob_end_flush();

$cmd = "./expect_script.sh";

$descriptorspec = array(
   0 => array("pipe", "r"),
   1 => array("pipe", "w"),
   2 => array("pipe", "w") 
);

$process = proc_open($cmd, $descriptorspec, $pipes, realpath('./'), array());

echo '<pre>';
if (is_resource($process)) {
    while ($s = fgets($pipes[1])) {
        print $s;

    }
}
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

So I wanted to get the real time output with automatic scroll at the end of the page with every new line appearance and I found this: [printing process output in realtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8765251/printing-process-output-in-realtime/8791415#8791415)

Then I added the proposed html code to my script as follows:

```
<html><head>
<script language="javascript">
var int = self.setInterval("window.scrollBy(0,1000);", 200);
</script>
</head>
<body>

<?php

ob_implicit_flush(true);
ob_end_flush();

$cmd = "./expect_script.sh";

$descriptorspec = array(
   0 => array("pipe", "r"),
   1 => array("pipe", "w"),
   2 => array("pipe", "w") 
);

$process = proc_open($cmd, $descriptorspec, $pipes, realpath('./'), array());

echo '<pre>';
if (is_resource($process)) {
    while ($s = fgets($pipes[1])) {
        print $s;

    }
}
echo '</pre>';
?>

</body>
</html>
```

However, when script finishes the web browser won't let me browse to the top of the page because it is still scrolling to the bottom.

How shall avoid it so that I can browse once the script is finished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) to repeat some task and never ask it to stop that.

you will need to stop setInterval from repeating itself , at the end of your php code add :

```
echo '</pre>';
echo '<script language="javascript">self.clearInterval(int);</script>';
```

also you will need to [close your proc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-close.php) process :

```
if (is_resource($process)) {
    while ($s = fgets($pipes[1])) {
        print $s;

    }
    proc_close($process);
}
```