# php flush not working

Tags: php, flush

```
<?php
for($i=0;$i<20;$i++)
{
    echo 'printing...<br />';
    ob_flush();
    flush();

    usleep(300000);
}

?>
```

Url that contains the code: http://domainsoutlook.com/sandbox/delayed.php

I have a dedicated server so I can make the changes. I am running apache and nginx as the proxy server.

Comment: Apache _and_ nginx? I think nginx would suffice.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: Should `ob_flush()` come after `flush()`, and also you the loop. need to start an output buffer with `ob_start()` before the loop

Comment: @robertpitt, could you please edit the code and answer it, so i test it and also select your answers as the right one if the code works. thanks

Comment: Duplicate of [PHP flush/ob_flush not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481235/php-flush-ob-flush-not-working)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're using `ob_flush` without `ob_start`, so there is nothing to flush for it.

It also depends on the webserver and proxy and its settings.

You should disable buffering for Nginx (add `proxy_buffering off;` to the config file and restart Nginx)

Also, check if your **php.ini** contains `output_buffering = Off` and `zlib.output_compression = Off`.

Comment: where is the nginx config file usually where i can add these values

Comment: do i add this line for nginx in the http core module

Comment: I have got proxy_buffering = off, zlib.output_compression = off and proxy_buffering off as well. But it is still not working. Could you please point me to some code or anything else please.

Comment: In that case, you should see if you really need "dynamic" printing and try other ways to do so (AJAX etc.)

Answer (score 48):

So that's what I found out:

Flush would not work under Apache's mod_gzip or Nginx's gzip because, logically, it is gzipping the content, and to do that it must buffer content to gzip it. Any sort of web server gzipping would affect this. In short, at the server side, we need to disable gzip and decrease the fastcgi buffer size. So:

- In php.ini:

  . output_buffering = Off

  . zlib.output_compression = Off
- In nginx.conf:

  . gzip  off;

  . proxy_buffering  off;

Also have this lines at hand, specially if you don't have acces to php.ini:

- @ini_set('zlib.output_compression',0);
- @ini_set('implicit_flush',1);
- @ob_end_clean();
- set_time_limit(0);

Last, if you have it, coment the code bellow:

- ob_start('ob_gzhandler');
- ob_flush();

**PHP test code:**

```
ob_implicit_flush(1);

for($i=0; $i<10; $i++){
    echo $i;

    //this is for the buffer achieve the minimum size in order to flush data
    echo str_repeat(' ',1024*64);

    sleep(1);
}
```

Comment: The last thing "echoing 64k **senseless** whitespace" did the trick for me. Thank you Roger.

Comment: . proxy_buffering off; was the problem in my config. Thanks!

Comment: I've done all these but not working on live centos7 apache with php 5.5. Working smooth locally even with output_buffering=4096

Comment: Using php7.2fpm the @ob_end_clean was what finally did it for me.

Comment: I needed 5 hours to find the problem why the SSE FLUSH was not working... `this is for the buffer achieve the minimum size in order to flush data`. Oh what the Hack! ... And there is not yet a way around it, as it seems: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57207571/1066234

Comment: Note: `echo str_repeat(' ', 4096);` seems to be sufficient. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php#51679

Comment: All methods seem to have a problem with Cloudflare - when you flush from server, it only flushes to Cloudflare. -- At least that's my theory. Any ideas?

Answer (score 12):

Main php file;

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/HTML; charset=utf-8');
header( 'Content-Encoding: none; ' );//disable apache compressed
session_start();
ob_end_flush();
ob_start();
set_time_limit(0);
error_reporting(0);

..... bla bla

for(each)........
{
   bla bla..
    echo "<br>>>>".$i."<<<br>";
    ob_flush();
    flush(); //ie working must

}
?>
```

it's working..

Comment: The Content-Encoding was what worked for me on nginx - without having to turn it off for the whole server. Thanks Emin!

Comment: Setting `Content-Encoding` finally made flushing work on Firefox, but somehow Chrome was still expecting a compressed response, so it threw an `ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED` error.

Answer (score 5):

You have to fill the buffer, so that it can be flushed to browser.
Use this after echo

```
echo str_pad('',4096)."\n";
```

Complete code:

```
<?php
     if (ob_get_level() == 0) ob_start();

     for( $i=0 ; $i<20 ; $i++) {
        echo 'printing...<br />';
        echo str_pad('',4096)."\n";

        ob_flush();
        flush();

        usleep(300000);
     }
     ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Comment: Awesome!  Such a simple thing to solve my problem but I havent found this solution or requirement anywhere else.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

In **php.ini**:

```
output_buffering = Off
zlib.output_compression = Off
```

In **nginx.conf**:

```
fastcgi_keep_conn on; # < solution
proxy_buffering off;
gzip off;
```

Comment: `fastcgi_keep_conn on` helped! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As I read, it seems a really hard problem to solve, and the only (dirty) way I found is writing something useless to output to fill the ≠ buffers.

- Without SSL

  - Without output_buffering, `flush` is needed.
    nginx buffers can be lowered until the PHP header size
  - With output_buffering, `ob_flush` need to be added to have the same behavior as above
- With SSL

  - There is another buffer for SSL and `NGX_SSL_BUFSIZE` is fixed in nginx compilation

Here is my test.php file (call it with `?size=...` to change space writing in the loop)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<?php
$vars = array('output_buffering', 'zlib.output_compression');
print('<p>');
foreach ($vars as $var) {
  print("$var : ");
  var_dump(ini_get($var));
  print('<br />');
}
print("ob_get_level() : " .ob_get_level());
print('</p>');
if (ob_get_level()) {
  $bytes = ob_get_length();
  ob_flush();
}

$nb_iterations = !empty($_GET['nb']) ? max(2, (int) $_GET['nb']) : 5;
$size = !empty($_GET['size']) ? $_GET['size'] : 0;

for ($i = 1; $i < $nb_iterations; $i++) {
  sleep(1);
  print(str_repeat(' ', 1024 * $size ));
  print("<p>wait $i s</p>");
  if (ob_get_level()) {
    $bytes += ob_get_length();
    print($bytes + strlen($bytes));
    ob_flush(); // this is working, results aren't depending on output_buffering value
  }
  flush(); // this is needed  
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

And the lower conf I can set is

```
location ~ ^/test.php$ {
  gzip off;
  fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm/ssl.socket;
  fastcgi_param   QUERY_STRING            $query_string;  
  fastcgi_param   REQUEST_METHOD          $request_method;
  fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME         $request_filename;   
  # if too low => upstream sent too big header while reading response header from upstream
  fastcgi_buffer_size 128; 
  fastcgi_buffers 2 128;  
  fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 128;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible cause is mod_security. It looks like it has it's own buffers. So if you are using it you will have to set :

```
SecResponseBodyAccess Off
```

Kind of a dirty workaround but so far that it the only way I got it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add to the Roger's answer.

If you are using FastCGI **php5-fpm** module within **Apache2** you must also make sure you are adding

**-flush**

argument in your Apache2 configuration, i.e.

```
<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
...
        FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi -flush -socket /tmp/php5-fpm.sock -idle-timeout 480 -pass-header Authorization
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your server api with

```
echo phpinfo();
```

If you found your server api

```
Server API :  CGI/FastCGI
```

in CentOS then add this line in "/etc/httpd/conf.d/fcgid.conf"

```
OutputBufferSize 0
```

To test, restart your Apache server and try below code

```
ob_start();
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i ++) {
    echo $i;
    echo '<br />';
    flush();
    ob_flush();
    sleep(1);
}
```

Comment: This is the one I'm looking for! Thanks @gsm ! I read all the answers/topic/blogs about this problem and all I needed is set the buffer size to zero in my Apache config file. Especially if you're running on Windows, and using `fcgid_module`, you should put `FcgidOutputBufferSize 0` to your httpd conf file where you set fcgid_module.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that browsers react differently. Chrome, for example, holds on to the input forever, and doesn't seem to care about displaying it any earlier.
Unsurprisingly, Firefox will display the input earlier, if the above tips (contributed by other stackoverflowers) are applied, so try with Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to flush only this way - adding session_write_close();

```
if (ob_get_level() == 0)
{
    if(!ob_start("ob_gzhandler"))ob_start();
}               
echo ('bla bla bla');

$ans=ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

header('Connection: close');
header('Content-Length: '.strlen($ans));
header('Status: 200');

echo $ans;

session_write_close();
ob_flush();
flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!ob_get_level()) ob_start();
echo json_encode(array('valid'=>true,'msg'=>'Flush occured.'));
$size = ob_get_length();
header("Content-Type: application/json");
// Set the content length of the response.
header("Content-Length: {$size}");
//Close the connection if you want to.
header("Connection: close");
// Flush all output.
ob_end_flush();
ob_flush();
flush();
// Close current session (if it exists).
if(session_id()) session_write_close();
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this code, and how does this answer the question? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried many times when using php-fpm with nginx. Many answers just instruct:

In php.ini:

```
output_buffering = Off

zlib.output_compression = Off
```

In nginx.conf:

```
gzip off;

proxy_buffering off;
```

BUT they forgot the very important setting in nginx.conf:

```
fastcgi_keep_conn on;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the only solution that worked for me without the padding.

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0); # remove the time limit for running the script
ob_end_clean();

#header('Cache-Control: no-cache'); # activate if chaching is an issue
#header('Pragma: no-cache'); # activate if chaching is an issue
header('Connection: close');
header('Transfer-Encoding: identity');

ob_implicit_flush(1);

for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
    echo json_encode(array(
        'timestamp'=>time(),
    ));
    usleep(500000);
}
?>
```

It gave the following output from curl:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 25 Nov 2023 11:54:24 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.57 (Unix) PHP/7.4.33
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.4.33
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: identity, chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
 
18
{"timestamp":1700913264}
18
{"timestamp":1700913265}
18
{"timestamp":1700913265}
18
{"timestamp":1700913266}
18
{"timestamp":1700913266}
0
```

It looks like this in the browser:

```
{"timestamp":1700913264}{"timestamp":1700913265}{"timestamp":1700913265}{"timestamp":1700913266}{"timestamp":1700913266}
```