# SSE (Event Source) flush() PHP

Tags: php, output-buffering, server-sent-events

At home, I'm trying to create a SSE Endpoint to use over website, true.
Then,I have the code fragment that's keeps request open, obviously (`while( true )`) ...
So then, I echo something and then use `ob_flush()` and `flush()` inside.

But, at home it's works properly, at remote host, no.

Localhost definition.
`System: Linux localhost 3.6.10-2.fc17.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Dec 11 18:07:34 UTC 2012 x86_64`

`Server API: Apache 2.0 Handler`

```
setting           local value        master value
output_buffering       0                 0
output_handler     no value           no value
```

And in server ... ( remote )
`Linux web521.xxx.net 3.2.2 #1 SMP Wed Feb 1 09:54:51 BRST 2012 x86_64`

`Server API FPM/FastCGI`

```
setting           local value        master value
output_buffering    no value    no value
output_handler  no value no value
```

Code fragment:

```
<?php

    while( true ) {
        // ...

        echo '...';
        ob_flush();
        flush();

        usleep( 50000 );

        // ...
    }

?>
```

Comment: Added ... echo '...' is event source data format, the problem is .. at remote host, the data not get flushed while scripts die.

Comment: Interesting.  Perhaps the FastCGI bits aren't passing along the data?

Comment: Probably ... some idea of how to fix ?

Comment: @HaroKen I've posted a similar script, which may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14120084/output-loading-message-in-php/14120513#14120513  You can try it and see if it works

Comment: BTW: it's safer to use `while(!connection_aborted())` instead of `while(true)`.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, and found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12301929/1314762

Try using `ob_end_flush()` in addition to `flush()`. I have no good answer as to why, but this worked for me when ob_flush() did not.

As an example (and I'm borrowing porneL's nice comment about using connection_aborted() instead of `while(true)`):

```
while( !connection_aborted() ) {
    // ...

    echo '...';
    ob_end_flush();
    flush();

    usleep( 50000 );

    // ...
}
```

Comment: ... but wouldn't ob_end_flush close the stream forcing a reconnect?