# PHP - Unbuffered While() Loop

Tags: php, while-loop

I am using php, I see `while()` loop in php. I want to ask something can we use
`while()` loop as `mysql_unbuffered_query()`.
This code make good understanding.

```
<?php
  echo 'While Loop is going to start';
  $i = 0;
  while($i <= 1000){
      echo 'Now number is '.$i;
      $i++;
  }
  echo 'Continue to running script';
?>
```

What happens when we run this code first of all this code read `while loop is going to start`
then read the while loop and create the statement to run `Now number is 0.....1000`
then read `Continue to running script` And when the code is **finished** it print out whole data.But I did not want this.
What I want.
First script read the `while Loop is going to start` and print out then read while loop and
print out `Now number is 0` then go `Continue to running script` and print out But the 
**back end** of script while loop still working, My mean both `while loop` and `continue script` working at once.
This give you more understanding.
**OUTPUT**(First time when script running is start)

```
 1 - While Loop is going to start
 2 - Now number is 0
 3 - Continue to running script
```

**OUTPUT**(Script running is continue)

```
 1 - While Loop is going to start
 2 - Now number is 0
 3 - Now number is 1
 . - ...............
 1000 - Now number is 1000
 1001 - Continue to running script
```

Might be this is **impossible**.If yes how I can do that.

But maybe this is possible like `mysql_unbuffered_query()`.
Like when while loop complete one cycle it print out the number and then other one and so on to complete.
**OUTPUT**(First time when while loop complete one cycle)

```
1 - While Loop is going to start
2 - Now number is 0
```

**OUTPUT**(while loop complete second cycle)

```
1 - While Loop is going to start
2 - Now number is 0
3 - Now number is 1
```

If this is possible, Please guide me how can I do that.
Thanks..............

Comment: you are doing everything right... just add a `flush();` after the echo statement

Comment: First of all mysql is deprecated.  Please use mysqli or PDO. Second, why not use ob_flush?

Comment: I'm using `flush();` but this would not working.
`<?php
     ini_set('implicit_flush', true);
  echo 'While Loop is going to start';
 $i = 0;
    while($i <= 1000){
       echo 'Now number is '.$i;
      flush();     
$i++;
     }
  echo 'Continue to running script';
 ?>`

Comment: Are you trying to say that you want to run your loop in a background thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running this script from the command line, output buffering is always off, and implicit flush is always on (according to https://www.php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php ). Because of this, I suspect you are running this PHP within a web server.

There are several PHP INI values which affect buffering, so you may wish to turn off these features:

```
<?php
    ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'off');
    ini_set('implicit_flush', 'on');
    ini_set('output_buffering', 'off');
    echo "While Loop is going to start.\n";
    $i = 0;
    while($i <= 10){
        echo "Now number is ".$i."\n<br>\n";
        $i++;
        sleep(1);
    }
    echo "\n<br>Finished running script\n\n";
?>
```

Even after all that, it's possible that PHP is behaving exactly as you want, but your web server is buffering the output. This thread may be of interest: [php flush not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706525/php-flush-not-working)

If you are using apache, you can add a line to an .htaccess file to turn off gzip compression (which automatically buffers until there's enough data to compress and send)
I found this page (http://www.bluehostforum.com/showthread.php?18996-Turning-off-Gzip) which describes the process, but it basically says to add

```
SetEnv no-gzip dont-vary
```

to your .htaccess file.

Can you confirm that the script I posted above works as you'd expect in your command line environment or not?

Also, if you are working within a web server, please post which web server you're using (IIS/apache/etc)

Answer (score 1):

You need threads or processes. This is a good thread: [Does PHP have threading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209774/does-php-have-threading)

My favorite answer there is https://stackoverflow.com/a/14201579/650405

Answer (score 0):

Forcing output to the browser works with the following calls in this order

```
ob_flush();
flush();
```

It, however, will not background any processing going on.