# How can i turn off the apache cache on SSL?

Tags: php, ssl, caching, flush

I can't use `flush()` to send data to the client, when I use a *SSL-connection (HTTPS)*. Without SSL, it works as expected. How can I turn off the *apache cache on SSL* to flush the data?

I've found a temporary workaround to fill the cache:

```
echo str_pad('',32768);
ob_flush();
flush();
```

**My System**:

> CentOS Linux 8.1.1911
>   PHP 7.4.3
>   Apache 2.4.37
>   OpenSSL 1.1.1c

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706525/php-flush-not-working

Comment: No that doesn't help. I have the workaround from this side.