# OB_Flush with IIS7.5 and PHP 7.0

Tags: php, iis, buffer

I'm building a web-application where a really slow backend exists. To be able to give the end-user feedback on the status of his requests, I'd like to use ob_flush to be able to pass the first part of the page (including some javascript that can provide more or less dynamic updates) while PHP is still crunching on the actual data in the page, but I cannot get ob_flush() to work.

I have a Windows 2008 R2 server, running iis 7.5 and PHP 7.0. 
I have followed every single step in [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7178514/php-flush-stopped-flushing-in-iis7-5), but to no use. 
I also use the sample code provided by the topic starter on that age.

Since my PHP version is much newer compared to the other thread, I have started a new thread instead of appending that old one. 
I've tried in several different browsers (Chrome, Edge and IE), but all give the same result (all output comes at once after 10 seconds of waiting for the page to load).

All together my question is: How do I get ob_flush() to work in IIS7.5 combined with PHP 7.0?

Thanks!

Comment: are you possibly looking for the `ob_clean()` function?

Comment: Hi, ob_clean() clears the buffer without sending any data to the client. That's not what I want.
See http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-clean.php

Answer (score 0):

OB_Flush just doesn't work anymore in IIS 7 or higher...
In the end I completely redesigned the application to work in a batchwise manner, where the web-interface stores requests done by the end user in a CSV file, while a background process (triggered through the task scheduler) processes the CSV files and produces new CSV file that PHP reads to provide the proper output.