# ob_flush() working on localhost but not online at GoDaddy

Tags: php, linux, buffer, flush, server-configuration

I have the following PHP script:

```
<?php 
ob_end_flush();
ob_start();
for ($i=0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    echo "Line ".$i."</br>";
    ob_flush();
    flush();
    sleep(1);
}
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

It works fine on WAMP localhost and prints new line each second, but online at GoDaddy economy hosting, it doesn't work. It shows the output after 10 seconds of nothing happens but the page loading.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Call the function phpinfo(); in a separate php script and run it on your host server to see if ob_flush() is enabled in your host server at GoDaddy

Comment: What exactly is enabled?

Comment: output_buffering = On, or output_buffering=4096 should be set instead of output_buffering = off in your PHP.ini

Comment: Tried both options, doesn't work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481235/php-flush-ob-flush-not-working

Comment: I tried all these options, works fine on localhost but not online. This is my issue.

Answer (score 2):

```
It will work fine....

if(!ob_get_level()) ob_start();
echo json_encode(array('valid'=>true,'msg'=>'Flush occured.'));
$size = ob_get_length();
header("Content-Type: application/json");
// Set the content length of the response.
header("Content-Length: {$size}");
//Close the connection if you want to.
header("Connection: close");
// Flush all output.
ob_end_flush();
ob_flush();
flush();
// Close current session (if it exists).
if(session_id()) session_write_close();
```