# Why does "PHP flush()" not working in IOS?

Tags: php, ios, flush

Following code working in all my browsers (IE, FF, Chrome, Safari Mac).

```
$out_text = " ";
echo str_pad($out_text, 1024*64);
flush();
```

Only in iOS (11.2.1 - my version) it is not working.
I tried now for hours a lot of different ways - without success.
Can somebody help?

Comment: Regarding working/not working - what is it supposed to do when it works and what happens instead when it doesn't work?

Comment: I want to flush the browser output (display a loading gif) bevor the script is finnished. In iOS the flush will be ignore.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Flush/ob\_flush not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481235/php-flush-ob-flush-not-working)

Comment: Thanks mike32. I tried the solutions in that tread - no success. I think it is something special with iOS?!

Answer (score 0):

Now I have found the reason.
If I remove the Doctype `<!DOCTYPE html>` it is working well.
But my next problem is, that I need this Doctype. I also tryed other doctypes without success.