# Echo 'string' while every long loop iteration (flush() not working)

Tags: php

I have a loop that takes very long to execute, and I want the script to display something whenever the loop iteration is done.

```
echo "Hello!";

flush();

for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i ++) {
    echo $i;
    //5-10 sec execution time
    flush();
}
```

This does not display the echos until the entire script is completed. What went wrong?

Comment: Various suggestions at http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php on getting flush working.

Comment: Here is the solution - https://stackoverflow.com/a/4978809/2083877

Answer (score 31, accepted):

From PHP Manual:

flush() may not be able to override the buffering scheme of your web server and it has no effect on any client-side buffering in the browser. It also doesn't affect PHP's userspace output buffering mechanism. This means you will have to call both ob_flush() and flush() to flush the ob output buffers if you are using those.

```
echo "Hello!";
flush();
ob_flush();

for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i ++) {
    echo $i;
    //5-10 sec execution time
    flush();
    ob_flush();
}
```

-or- you can flush and turn off Buffering

```
<?php
//Flush (send) the output buffer and turn off output buffering
while (ob_get_level() > 0)
    ob_end_flush();

echo "Hello!";

for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i ++) {
    echo $i . "\r\n";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you first do:

`@ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 0);
@ini_set('implicit_flush', 1);
@ob_end_clean();`

and then just `flush();` every time you need to output your echo'es to the browser.

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
while (@ob_end_flush());      
ob_implicit_flush(true);

echo "first line visible to the browser";
echo str_pad("",1024," ");
echo "<br />";

sleep(5);

echo "second line visible to the browser after 5 secs";
```

Just notice that this way you're actually disabling the output buffer for your current script. So if you're trying to 'ob_end_flush()' after that you'll get a warning that there is no buffer to close.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the desired behavior **isn't possible is a deterministic/stable way** using pure PHP and HTML.

If and how a browser renders a partial page depends on the browser, proxies and caches. Thus, even if the stuff works on your test machine, it's likely, that it does not on your production system.

The library [xAjax](http://www.xajax-project.org/) provides a **well-integrated solution to manage AJAX style updates with PHP**. While xAjax might be dead as a project (at least right now), it still works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to also use ob_flush() sometimes both are needed to work.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure to output a Content-type header first. Flushing doesn't work for me without:

```
header( 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
for($i=0; $i<10; ++$i)  {
    echo "Loop<br />\n";
    ob_flush();
    flush();
    sleep(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this on the **header** of the script:

```
ob_start();
ob_implicit_flush();
```

Implicit flushing will result in a flush operation after every output call so that explicit calls to flush() will no longer be needed.
Please note that adding implicit flushing in the script execution affects on **performance**. You can add a debugging mode for your script like:

```
ob_start();
define(DEBUG, 1);

if(DEBUG){
    ob_implicit_flush();
}
```