# how to output php result in real time in browser?

Tags: php, buffer

I've created this code and it shows next integer every second but there are also errors along with the output.

```
<?php

ob_implicit_flush();
for ($i = 0; $i < 30; $i++) {
  echo "-> $i <br>\n";
  ob_end_flush();
  ob_end_clean();
  sleep(1);
}

?>
```

error:

```
Notice: ob_end_flush(): failed to delete and flush buffer. No buffer to delete or flush in c:\apache\www\TEST.PHP on line 6
Notice: ob_end_clean(): failed to delete buffer. No buffer to delete in C:\apache\www\TEST.PHP on line 7
-> 4
```

Putting `@` sign on the ob_* functions to silence these errors also disables realtime output.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6556790/3933332

Comment: that one works: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25937710/393087

Comment: worked for me !!! problem might elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You are ending `ob_end_flush();`

You should use only this:

```
ob_flush();
```

Comment: with `ob_flush();` it also doesn't work, output is buffered as usual.