# PHP echo after every iteration in foreach loop

Tags: php, loops, foreach, echo

I'm trying to echo after every iteration of a foreach loop in PHP.  The echos aren't rendering until they are all done.  I've tried the suggestions from various posts but none are working. Some of my code is:

```
echo $epTitle . "<br>";
echo "<div>" . '<img src="' . $imgSrc . '" height="70" width="70">';
echo "<button onclick='grabVid(" . '"' . $pageUrl . '"' ..")'>Grab</button>";
```

I've tried the following:

```
flush();
```

.

```
flush();
ob_flush();
```

.

```
while (ob_get_level() > 0)
ob_end_flush();
```

.

```
@ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 0);
@ini_set('implicit_flush', 1);
@ob_end_clean();
```

and other suggestions from:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php
and
[Echo 'string' while every long loop iteration (flush() not working)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6556790/echo-string-while-every-long-loop-iteration-flush-not-working)

Any suggestions?  Thanks.

Comment: The only way I've accomplished this succesfully has been using Ajax requests. Otherwise the PHP script will process all and then send the output back.

Comment: @ MarkSkayff I'm using Ajax post method which posts to the above script.  It still doesn't echo out after each iteration.

Comment: Because that isn't how HTTP normally works.  Web servers send headers then a response body.   Nothing is sent until the request is done so the proper headers are sent (HTTP status code, content type, content length).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using XHR (AJAX) and want to stream the response, you need to periodically check on it using [`onprogress`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequestEventTarget/onprogress). The [`onreadystatechange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/onreadystatechange) event will not fire whilst the response is being received, because the [`readyState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readyState) will always be `loading` and not change until the request has completed.

Here is a good article on the subject:

[PHP Streaming and Output Buffering explained](https://www.sitepoint.com/php-streaming-output-buffering-explained/)

It contains this sample JavaScript for the XHR part:

```
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "response.php", true);
xhr.onprogress = function(e) {
  alert(e.currentTarget.responseText);
}
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
    console.log("Complete = " + xhr.responseText);
  }
}
xhr.send();
```

(I don't know if there's any reason why the example uses `e.currentTarget` instead of `xhr` inside the `onprogress` event handler - I just copied the example as it is.)

If you're planning on doing this loop for longer than 30 seconds, your PHP script will probably be killed.  You can [extend the default time limit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) but if you're site has many users, you want requests to be short as possible for optimum server availability.

This means rewriting your loop so that each iteration is a single HTTP request.

Answer (score 0):

Using ob_flush() right after the echo, worked for me.

Comment: ob_flush(); Did not work but ob_flush(); flush(); after echo worked for me.