# how to show results one by one in codeigniter 4 for loop with ob_flush

Tags: xmlhttprequest, codeigniter-4

my problem is: i wan to show data in real time with codeigniter 4

This code results will be out once the for loop is ended

what i wan to do is echo results one by one

i have alrady done this before but not with codeigniter, it's was my own code without any framwork

but now i am stiked here 1 week and no rsults

i use codeigniter 4

and i use aapanel in my server

and this is my  phpinfo
[image: my php info]

my function in my controller Count.php

```
function startcounter(){
    $count = $this-\>request-\>getPost("count");
    if (ob_get_level() == 0) ob_start();
    for($i=0; $i\<=$count; $i++){
        echo $i;
        ob_flush();
        flush();
        sleep(1);
    }
    ob_end_flush(); 
    exit();
}
```

My javascript

```
function startcounter(){
    data = "count=5";
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', baseUrl+'/count/startcounter', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.send(data);  
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 1) {
            resp = xhr.response;
            arrs = resp;
            if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.LOADING) {
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
            }
            if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                alert('Done')
            }
        }
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Echo 'string' while every long loop iteration (flush() not working)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6556790/echo-string-while-every-long-loop-iteration-flush-not-working)

Comment: No, the response that you montioned is no relation with codeigniter 4

Comment: If something works in vanilla PHP, it should work as well in almost any PHP-based framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function testflush(){
    ini_set('output_buffering','on');
    ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 0);
    ini_set('max_execution_time', '3000');
    ob_implicit_flush();
    $response = service('response');
    $response->send();
    ob_end_flush();
    flush();
    for($i=0; $i<=99; $i++){
       echo "Test".$i;
       ob_flush();
       flush();
       sleep(1);
    }
  return $this->response->setJSON(''); // send empty json response (This is 
  the most important thing)
}
```