# Force browser to render a partial response immediately

Tags: internet-explorer, http, google-chrome

When an HTTP Response contains buffered output (ie, with `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`) and there is a delay between chunks, Chrome and Internet Explorer do not display the response until the entire response has been received.  Firefox will display the content as it arrives.

Try [this test page](http://jumpingfishes.com/progresstest.ashx) in Firefox, then Chrome or IE.

Is there a way to force Chrome and Internet Explorer to render content as it is received, rather than waiting for the complete response?  Some HTTP header perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to send a large chunk of data initially to force the browser to start rendering the output.  In my testing, 1024 characters is enough to get Chrome to start rendering the response.  IE10 doesn't respond until 4065 characters are received.

This is a bit of a hack, but does the job.

Comment: I have used the 4k chunk "trick" to force rendering since about the year 2002, but it stopped working for me in the last year and I have not been able to find a work around. I have sent some huge chunks to no effect, yet once a threshold is reached, chrom(ium) starts rendering as data is received (console like) which is what I need.

Comment: Just checked and it still works for me.  Tested using Chrome 117.  My [old test page](https://jumpingfishes.com/progresstest2.ashx) pads the first chunk with whitespace so that it is 4065 characters, and then sends two characters (`" ."`) every second for 10 minutes.  When I load it in chrome, it starts rendering those dots right away.  Unlike [the original test page from the question](http://jumpingfishes.com/progresstest.ashx), which still doesn't rendering anything in chrome until the entire response is received.

Comment: I thank @gilly3 for providing the link to his test page, which worked just fine in my browser, I wrote a very simple script to send exactly what his sent and of course it failed. I ended up watching both scripts on the network tab of developer tools in the browser. Even though both scripts were sending the same bytes on the same timeline, they were being received very differently in the browser. I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8882383/

Answer (score 0):

Google Closure's browserchannel has the server sending a 290 byte string to force IE to render content from the first chunk:

See "290 byte string 7cca694...e693af" at https://code.google.com/p/libevent-browserchannel-server/wiki/BrowserChannelProtocol