Why does Firefox not showing partially-received HTML in this simple example
I've written a simple NodeJS code to play with HTML streaming, similar to how Next.js do it, but without React. The code first send the placeholder HTML as a partial HTML fragment, then it stalls the request, and send the <script> tag which modifies the placeholder.
https://gist.github.com/peat-psuwit/53a0b13dfda8781ac34cf6e66cc92ec0 (EDIT: also included below)
On Chrome, this exhibit expected result: the text "Loading..." is shown while the HTTP request stalls. Then, after 5 seconds, the script which modifies the word "Loading..." is sent in the same request, and word "Hello, world!" is shown.
However, on Firefox, it simply waits until the whole HTTP request is finished before rending. This means that it simply shows the white page for 5 seconds, and then it skips to "Hello, world!" state.
My understanding is that, as I call res.write(), NodeJS automatically uses HTTP's chunked transfer capability to transfer the skeleton, partial HTML code to the browser first, which allows "Loading..." text to be seen. My question is why it doesn't work with Firefox? Or maybe I'm supposed to do additional thing to make it works, and it works on Chrome by accident?
This is Chrome (Chromium) 124.0.6367.60 and Firefox 124.0.2 on Ubuntu 22.04.

The sample code in question:
import { setTimeout } from "node:timers/promises";
import express from "express";

/* Simple HTML streaming concept, inspired by now NextJS do it, but without React.
 * TODO: figure out why in the world does Firefox not show the "Loading..." as soon
 * as it's received.
*/

async function getContent() {
  await setTimeout(5000);

  return {
    id: "main-content",
    innerHTML: "<h1>Hello, world!</h1>",
  };
}

const app = express();

app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  res.status(200);

  // TODO: maybe de-indent.
  res.write(`
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Hello, world</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="main-content">Loading...</div>
  `);

  let content = await getContent();

  res.write(`
        <script>
          document.getElementById(${JSON.stringify(content.id)}).innerHTML = ${JSON.stringify(content.innerHTML)};
        </script>
  `);

  res.write(`
      </body>
    </html>
  `);

  res.end();
});

console.log("http://localhost:3000");
app.listen(3000);


Please, add all relevant code to the question, it needs to be understandable without navigating to external link. This is very specific to how browsers render, which is not regulated. E.g. it can be the opposite if the chunks are small https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14409817 . In your case older and newer firefox versions behave differently. It's possible to trigger this with different chunk sizes in different browsers, "Loading" is not enough for consistent behaviour. Another problem here is html and the way it's rendered, ff can output it immediately if it's text/plain like in the link.

I don't remember exactly how the requests are timed in Next but I doubt it solely relies on http streaming for gradual rendering. If you have a specific case to address, this could be XY problem

Does this answer your question? Node.js: chunked transfer encoding

Answering my own question, it turns out the "additional thing" is this line:
res.header('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8');

My logic goes that, without this header, Firefox probably can't infer that the partial response is HTML or what charset it is. Thus Firefox probably buffers the response until it has enough to be confident about the content type or the charset. With the header, Firefox doesn't have to do the guesswork and can start parsing the response as an HTML right away.
I've included the fix, along with a lot more comments, in the new gist here and will also reproduce below.

/*
 * Simple HTML streaming concept, inspired by how NextJS do it, but without
 * React.
 *
 * It works by initially sending a skeleton HTML to the browser, but,
 * importantly, this skeleton is unclosed, which allows server to stream in
 * more content. However, you cannot go back to edit the HTML content you've
 * already sent. Or can you???
 *
 * Turns out, if the additional content is a <script> tag which changes the
 * innerHTML of an existing node, then you _can_ change anything you've already
 * sent. This is essentially now Next.js can send stream additional stuff to the
 * page under the same connection without additional requests, however RSC
 * (React Server Component) payload is used instead of raw HTML.
 *
 * Have fun!
 * 
 * Author: Ratchanan Srirattanamet
 * SPDX-License-Identifier: CC0-1.0
 */

import { setTimeout } from "node:timers/promises";
import express from "express";

async function getContent() {
  // Simulates querying DB, doing formatting etc. (Exacerbated).
  await setTimeout(5000);

  return {
    id: "main-content",
    innerHTML: "<h1>Hello, world!</h1>",
  };
}

const app = express();

app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  res.status(200);
  // Without this, browsers might not be able to infer from the partial response
  // that this is an HTML and might not start rendering.
  res.header('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8');

  // The skeleton HTML.
  // TODO: maybe de-indent.
  res.write(`
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Hello, world</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="main-content">Loading...</div>
  `);

  // Now let's generate the actual content.
  let content = await getContent();

  // And then send the JS to instruct the browser to plug the content into the
  // skeleton.
  res.write(`
        <script>
          document.getElementById(${JSON.stringify(content.id)}).innerHTML = ${JSON.stringify(content.innerHTML)};
        </script>
  `);

  // Now that everything is sent to the client. Be courteous and send the
  // closing tags to the client. This is probably not strictly needed, but why
  // not?
  res.write(`
      </body>
    </html>
  `);

  // And finally, closes the request-response cycle.
  res.end();
});

console.log("http://localhost:3000");
app.listen(3000);


