# js counter not displaying in php

Tags: php, javascript, counter

I do not understand why I am not seeing each number diaplyed in the div.

My code...

```
<head>
    <script>
        function countit(i)
        {
            document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = i;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="counter"></div>

<script>countit(1)</script>
<?php sleep(1); ?>
<script>countit(2)</script>
<?php sleep(1); ?>
<script>countit(3)</script>

</body>
```

I have a php script which process several records from a database and I want to display a counter
of the current recod being processed. I thought JS was the way to do that. I saw something very similiar to the code above recommended on so.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: first of all, you're mixing server-side and client side scripting. That makes you confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP is a server side language, while Javascript is client side. I'm guessing you are simply seeing `3` in you `counter` div. The reason is because the PHP `sleep(1)` is happening before the page is even rendered. You need use a `setInterval` in Javascript to accomplish what you are trying to do.

Comment: ok. maybe I am taking the wrong appraoch to this. If I have a php script that is processing a large table and taking quite some time (minutes actually), how can I display a counter on the page to let the user know where they are in the process?

Comment: AJAX is what you need to be using for that.

Comment: That sounds like what I need. Off to research. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

PHP buffers the output and doesn't send the page until it has finished running. The sleeps do not run between execution of script elements.

Rewrite your logic to use a [JavaScript `setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval) instead.

Alternatively, [disable or avoid output buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8882383/how-to-disable-output-buffering-in-php) in your PHP script, but note that this is likely to have implications on the ability of browsers to cache your page.

Comment: The 'sleeps' are just there so I could see the count changing. I want to execute the js function from different places in my php code, ie: after processing x number of records, call teh js function and update the count. I will investigate disabling output buffering and see where that leads me.

Comment: @user2076615: `execute the js function from different places in my php code`.  It doesn't work that way.  PHP is ran *before* the browser even sees the JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your php code executes on your server, while you need code to execute on the client (JavaScript) for this to work:

```
<script>
  var idx = 1;
  var doCount= function(){
      if(idx >= 3) return;
      countit(idx);
      setTimeout(doCount,1000);         
  };
  doCount();


</script>
```

remove the following:

```
<?php sleep(1); ?>
<script>countit(2)</script>
<?php sleep(1); ?>
<script>countit(3)</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code waits 2 seconds and the browser receives:

```
<head>
    <script>
        function countit(i)
        {
            document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = i;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="counter"></div>

<script>countit(1)</script>

<script>countit(2)</script>

<script>countit(3)</script>

</body>
```

that's probably not what you want.
let's try something like this:

```
<script>
    var i = 1;
    function counter()
    {
       if (i < 4)
       {
         countit(i);
         i++;
         window.setTimeout(counter,1000);
       }
    }

    counter();
</script>
```