# Is it possible to send the output before end of the php script?

Tags: php

Is it possible to send the output of a php script before the end of the script so we can make any unrelated operations to the output ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8882383/how-to-disable-output-buffering-in-php

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking about.  Do you want to turn off output buffering?

Comment: Other than flushing the output?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can  :

on the top of the script define those :

```
ini_set("implicit_flush", 1);
while (@ob_end_flush());
ob_implicit_flush(true);
```

after any output (echo print or print_r) call thise two functions to flush it :

```
flush();
ob_flush();
```

Comment: not working.. what is this while loop without content?