# PHP Cli Output after run

Tags: php, command-line-interface

```
for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
      echo $i . "\n";
      sleep(1);
}
```

This is the code I run. Instead of showing a number each second, the php CLI decides to wait and after everything is executed shows

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

Why is this happening, how can I make it "real-time" ?

**EDIT**: Found the problem: because I included WP-Core (Wordpress) the output somehow buffered, if I remove the wp-core it is all fine. For more info, when including the wp_core there are some wp notices that are being logged in separate file.

Comment: This can happen if output buffering is on. Kindly refer this link,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8882383/how-to-disable-output-buffering-in-php

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable output buffering, or flush the buffer.  You really only need the ob for requests that come over HTTP, as it lets you do all your server-side processing without having to worry about the connection to the client.

```
for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
      echo $i . "\n";
      sleep(1);

      flush();
      ob_flush();
}
```

Alternatively, if you can't change the code, you can disable output buffering completely in your CLI php.ini

```
output_buffering=Off
```

Comment: Thank, this works, but seems the problem with me is the WP Core

Comment: I set output_buffering to Off and implicit_flush to On, did not help :(

Comment: When I remove the wordpress core includes, it works even without flush, if I include the wordpress core, output comes after execution

Answer (score 0):

`Servers` usually buffer the output of a server side script until there's enough in it to output try something like this. Combination of setting output buffering off and manually flushing the buffer. Note the implcit `flush` line and the flush and `ob_flush` lines.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    echo $i . "</br>";
    sleep(1);
    flush();
    ob_flush();
}
```

for more info about `ob-flush`  please read http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php

Comment: Thank, this works, but seems the problem with me is the WP Core