# Why does Output_buffering option remain ON regardless of php.ini OFF setting?

Tags: wamp, output-buffering, php

I want to change the output_buffering setting on my local WAMP server to OFF.
Currently it is set to ON as my phpinfo.php file says:
output_buffering    4096    4096

The problem is that although I am changing the php.ini file which is located at the location mentioned in the phpinfo.php information to look like this:

output_buffering
   Default Value: Off
   Development Value: Off
   Production Value: Off

OR this:

output_buffering
   Default Value: Off
   Development Value: 0
   Production Value: 0

The values of the output_buffering setting remain the same after restarting the WAMP server:
output_buffering    4096    4096

Also, if I try echoing the output_buffering setting with this php function, I get a result of 4096:

echo ini_get('output_buffering');

Can someone please help me understand why this is happening and how to fix it?

Best regards,
Peter

Comment: Did you restart php/apache after changing the config file?

Comment: Yes. I also said that in the question - I closed the local server and started it again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8882383/how-to-disable-output-buffering-in-php

Comment: I tried that solution from the mentioned post before asking this question. At point 1 the author of the highest ranked answer mentions editing the php.ini file (which I did with no result). Also another solution is "Turning off output_buffering in your Apache config using php_flag "output_buffering" Off" - I don't know where to find that Apache config file.