# Disabling output_buffering in WHM/cPanel

Tags: php, apache, cpanel, whm, output-buffering

Spent several hours on this now, to no avail.

Simply trying to turn output buffering off on a clients WHM install, for a simple XHR response log. For testing, I have a very simple PHP script, which on the CLI does exactly what it needs to, however through a web browser, it executes the whole script before returning everything.

Environment - WHM, PHP 5.6, PHP FPM, Apache 2.4

Steps taken so far:

1. Ensured gzip is off (confirmed via https://checkgzipcompression.com)
2. In the .htaccess file added `SetEnv no-gzip 1` (confirmed as it toggles the above step on/off
3. Set in the php.ini file `output_buffering = 0` and `zlib.output_compression = Off`
4. Set in http.conf `FcgidOutputBufferSize 0` and restarted apache

Any help or assistance would be gratefully received, I've done an extensive search on Stack Overflow and tried everything that I've found however with no luck.

Comment: Did you find this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8882383/how-to-disable-output-buffering-in-php and tried flushing? Also note that it could be a browser behaviour (let me try to find a source for that)...

Comment: This might help: http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php. By the way, what does WHM mean?

Comment: @KasperAgg hover your mouse over the "whm" tag in the question ;).

Comment: I don't have a mouse ;-)

Comment: @KasperAgg tried all of those I'm afraid

Comment: Could you share some of that code? What browser did you test with? Did you test with curl? What is the whole script and what is everything? What are you expecting instead?