# Form Action file executing on the same page?

Tags: php, submit

I have a form, on its action i have a php file, i want that when i click submit, it should first open the action php (means view in browser), and then start executing the code in it.

form tag is like this

```
<form action="myScript.php" method="post"></form>
```

right now what happen is, when i click submit, it stays on the same page and start executing the php file, when it is done then, then it shows the script file page in browser.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery POST and do what ever you want:
[jQuery.POST](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Answer (score 0):

Is the `<input type="submit">` tags etc. inside the `<form>` tags. If not, then the input buttons are pointless, and just return false. 
Your code should look like this:

```
<form action="myScript.php" method="post">
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Does this help?

Kai :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have to execute the PHP in order to generate the page that is shown in the browser as a result of the POST. Even if your PHP is generating the page and then performing a long operation, output buffering and compression will defeat you, so you will need to turn them off. See [How to flush output after each `echo` call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133209/) for other things you may have to do to get your output to appear immediately.