# multiple callback using jquery .post ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Is it possible to get multiple callbacks using jQuery `.post` for a ajax upload of an image to php?
I am sending an image to the server for processing thru binary string and would like to hav the front end display status when the image has uploaded then a processing icon.

Currently I am using the standard .post but ideally this is the scenario i am looking for -
jquery:

```
$.post( 'process.php', { myvar:myvar}, function(data){

    if(data=='callback_1'){
        // process 1
    }else if(data=='callback_2'){
        // process 2
    }

});
```

php:

```
$myvar = $_POST['myvar'];

// after process 1
echo 'callback_1'

// after process 2
echo 'callback_2'
```

Comment: You might check out the source for the [jQuery file upload](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) plugin, which does exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Austen ive seen this but couldnt get it to work properly on firefox, chrome.  i get an error icon under the image title on the left

Comment: That's too bad. That plugin has saved me a lot of trouble. Perhaps another SO question could solve your problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

I set an array in the php script

```
$r['callback_one'] = 'complete';
$r['callback_two'] = 'fail';

echo json.encode($r);
```

javascript:

```
r = JSON.parse(data);
if (r.callback_one === 'complete){//do something};
```

of course this still sends the callbacks all at once, which may not be what you are after.

---

the only thing i can think of if you need to try and get things sequentially is to use
flushing:

[How to flush output after each `echo` call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133209/how-to-flush-output-after-each-echo-call)

```
ob_end_flush();

# CODE THAT NEEDS IMMEDIATE FLUSHING

ob_start();
```

What may even be happening is that the client does not receive the packet from the server until the server has built up enough characters to send what it considers a packet worth sending.

Old Answer:

You could use ob_implicit_flush which will tell output buffering to turn off buffering for a while:

```
ob_implicit_flush(true);

# CODE THAT NEEDS IMMEDIATE FLUSHING

ob_implicit_flush(false);
```