# Why is a PHP script waiting "to finish script" before any echo/output?

Tags: php, echo

Considering a simple script

```
<?php 
echo "hi";
foreach ($_GET['arr'] as $a)
{
 echo $a ."<br>";
}
echo "<p>Masel tov</p>";
foreach ($_GET['arr2'] as $a)
{
 echo $a ."<br>";
}
```

i expect the script to echo continuously. Instead the script does echo all-at-once when finished. Even the first "`hi`" gets echoed after 1 minute when the script finishes.

Is there a setting to prevent this from happen or why is that so?

Comment: Here is how to echo immediately - https://stackoverflow.com/a/4978809/2083877

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a function [ob_implicit_flush](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-implicit-flush.php) that can be used to enable/disable automatic flushing after each output call. But have a look at the comments on the PHP manual before using it.

Answer (score 5):

Depending on your config, output is cached until completion. You can force a flush with either `ob_flush()` or `flush()`. Sadly many modern browser also dont update until page load is complete, no matter how often you flush.

- flush http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php
- ob_flush http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php

Configuration Settings for PHP's output buffering.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php

Answer (score 2):

Check with this

```
if (ob_get_level() == 0)
{
    ob_start();
} 
for ($i = 1; $i<=10; $i++){
        echo "<br> Task {$i} processing ";
        ob_flush();
        flush();
        sleep(1);
}
echo "<br /> All tasks finished";
ob_end_flush();
```

Comment: Very nice! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want displaying the items one by one and keep clean code that works with every server setup,  you might consider using ajax. I don't like flushing the buffer unless there are no other options to accomplish the task.

If your project isn't a webproject you might consider running your code in the php console (command line) to receive immediate output.

Answer (score -1):

PHP sends, as you noticed, all data at once (the moment the script has finished) - you search for something like this https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.ob-get-contents.php :

```
<?php

ob_start();

echo "Hello ";

$out1 = ob_get_contents();

echo "World";

$out2 = ob_get_contents();

ob_end_clean();

var_dump($out1, $out2);
?>
```