# Display jquery response before php script complete execution

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have this simple JQUERY code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $(document).on('click', 'button', function(){
         $.post('post.php',
         {
             test: 'yes'
         },
         function(data, textStatus)
         {
            alert(data);
         });
      }); 
});
```

And this `post.php` page:

```
<?php

/* do some stuff that takes time */
echo '1';

?>
```

So i submit a POST request to PHP page using JQUERY and want to alert the response which is  `1` in the above example. The problem is that the script takes sometime to fully execute which in return slows down the response.

This is just a very simplified example. Is there a way to get the response before the full loading of the PHP script? I tried to echo before the rest of the script but it doesn't matter as the response won't be sent before the script completes all the tasks.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133209/how-to-flush-output-after-each-echo-call

Answer (score 0):

You can try [flushing](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php) the buffer.