# php - echo not showing without other echo

Tags: php, echo

I got this error and I don't really know why.

```
switch($op) 
{
    case "check" : 
        $result = $Login->login($data,array()); 
        break;  
}

echo json_encode($result);
```

and, it's not echoing the string.

if I put an echo before or after, it works

```
echo json_encode($result);
echo '.';
```

returns

```
{"status":false,"errID":4,"errTxt":"Invalid password"}.
```

var_dump returns

```
string(50ish) "{"status":false,"errID":4,"errTxt":"Invalid password"}"
```

Any ideeas why it's not echoing it without other stuff echoed too?

Edit

```
$str = json_encode($result);  
echo $str;
```

returns nothing but

```
$str = json_encode($result);  
$str .= '-';
echo $str;
```

returns

```
{"status":false,"errID":3,"errTxt":"Invalid email"}-
```

So it won't echo the string, but if I append something after it, it will echo it.

LE: with die() after echo sill nothing

Comment: can you show us your login() function

Comment: Try echo json_encode($result); die(); or echo json_encode($result); exit(); and check please.

Comment: Probably it's because of output buffering, try to check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133209/how-to-flush-output-after-each-echo-call)

Comment: How about the print family?

Comment: I can not reproduce it. Maybe you need to restart your webserver... Sounds silly, but has preventet me for hours of debugging in my life ;)