# php echo first row wait/sleep then echo second row

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to know is there a way to echo first row from table in database wait/sleep for 5 seconds and then echo the second row?

Thank you in advance for your help!

```
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '','database');
$strSql=$conn->query("SELECT words FROM load ORDER BY id ASC ");
if($strSql->num_rows >0) {
    while ($row = $strSql->fetch_assoc()) {
    $rows[]=$row;
    foreach($rows as $row){
       $words1=$row['words'];
               echo '<div class="animatedText"> '.$words1.'</div>';
       //let's say sleep(5); and then print second row???
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php

Comment: Use js/ajax for this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133209/how-to-flush-output-after-each-echo-call

Comment: output buffering would work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using [output buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832010/what-is-output-buffering). For example:

```
header( 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );

while ($row = $strSql->fetch_assoc()) {
      $rows[]=$row;
       foreach($rows as $row){
            $words1=$row['words'];
            echo '<div class="animatedText"> ';
            echo $words1;
            echo '</div>';
            flush();
            ob_flush();
            sleep(5);
           }
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `sleep()` function:

```
echo '<div class="animatedText"> ';
while ($row = $strSql->fetch_assoc()) {

      $rows[]=$row;

       foreach($rows as $row){
           $words1=$row['words'];

           echo $words1;
           sleep(5);

           }

       }
echo '</div>';
```

[read more](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php)

Comment: I have tried that, but it waits 5 sec and then echo first row...i need something like refresh and echo second row? maybe i don't explaining very well:) sorry

Comment: to echo the second row after 5 sec. in the same div. i need to display first row in a div, wait 5 sec and display second row in the same div

Comment: @YSimeonov in this case you print div tag outside the loop once.

Comment: noc2spam ツ  yes actually it is not working the way i want. I'm trying ob_flush() your suggestion :) thanks