# How to echo result since one single curl request is completed via PHP-cUrl multiple-thread

Tags: php, curl

In `test.html`,`demo`word included only。

```
    demo
```

---

`curl.php`

```
<php?

//init curl
$chArr=[];
for($i=0;$i<500;$i++){
    $chArr[$i]=curl_init("http://dev.site/test.html");
    curl_setopt($chArr[$i],CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
}

//create curl
$mh = curl_multi_init(); 
foreach($chArr as $k => $ch){
    curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$ch); 
}

$running = null;

do{
    curl_multi_exec($mh,$running); 
}while($running > 0); 

//start multi-thread
foreach($chArr as $k => $ch){
    $result[$k]= curl_multi_getcontent($ch);  

    //and echo out the result
    echo "$result[$k]\n"      

    curl_multi_remove_handle($mh,$ch);
}

curl_multi_close($mh);
```

---

I've set 500 requests,about 10s later got the output and there is no response during processing
[image: no response]

---

Is there anyway to display the result and give me a Feedback since every single curl request is done,just like below?

[image]

---

PS:if PHP is hard to do this so,I could accept Nodejs,Python etc.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35891746/1437261

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use [ob_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) and [ob_end_flush()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-flush.php).

**ob_start()** turns on the output buffering, so put that at the top of the for loop before echoing the output.

and

**ob_end_flush()** sends the output buffer and turn off output buffering.

So your code might look like this,

```
foreach($chArr as $k => $ch){
    ob_start();
    $result[$k]= curl_multi_getcontent($ch);  

    //and echo out the result
    echo "$result[$k]\n"      
    ob_end_flush();
    curl_multi_remove_handle($mh,$ch);
}
```

Comment: sorry guy,I did like what said，however I still get the same thing，terminal only display the result when that all 500 curl were done,I exactly what php give me a feed back since every single curl request is completed