# ob_flush and flush does not work in appweb

Tags: php

This code works well in apache. It pushes a message to the client every second.

But it doesn't work in appweb. Instead, it pushes a message to the client when all message are collected

This is the php code:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
ob_start();
$i = 1;
while ($i<10) {
    echo $i++;
    ob_flush();
    flush();
    sleep(1);
}
?>
```

I used the default configuration.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to flush output after each \`echo\` call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133209/how-to-flush-output-after-each-echo-call)

Comment: It works well in apache, but it does not work in appweb.

Comment: Why have you used `set_time_limit(0);` . I dont understand the meaning of time limit 0

Comment: it does work no matter if it has the function set_time_limit(0).