# Execute shell, get and display result realtime using PHP

Tags: php, python, shell, real-time

I need to do some long process using Python which will be called using PHP(my main language) and display the result real time.

Lets say this is my Python script(`a.py`).

```
import time

for x in range(10):
    print "S;adasdasd;",x
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

I have try so many example from internet but always get same result.
PHP always wait until script is done then displaying it.

Here is one of so many code i have tried.

```
    header( 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
    $handle = popen('python folder\\a.py', 'r');
    while (!feof($handle)) {
            echo fgets($handle);
            flush();
            ob_flush();
    }
    pclose($handle);
```

Did I miss something?

Comment: Try adding a character set as a header in your PHP. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12740522/128161

Comment: tried but gives same result,
i have update the question

Comment: How about using `fread($handle, 1024); ` instead of `fgets`?

Comment: nope.still gives me the same result,
did i need to config my PHP or something?

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest. It could be something to do with `popen` rather than using `fopen`. Is it possible you could alter the code slightly to use `fopen` and set the URL to a website and just output the contents line by line. If that works then the issue would lie within `popen` rather than your server config, so may help to narrow down the issue.

Comment: okay, thankyou, ill try to look into it..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> PHP always wait until script is done then displaying it.

In this case, it's not PHP's fault; it's because Python fully buffers its standard output if that goes to a pipe. Fortunately, Python has the handy option `-u` to disable stdout and stderr buffering, so using

```
    $handle = popen('python -u folder\\a.py', 'r');
```

solves the problem. See also [Disable output buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/disable-output-buffering).

Comment: Been looking for a solution for long and this really fixed it. Can't believe it was that simple.