# How to print content made with php before all the script is executed

Tags: php

I coded that script in php:

```
foreach($hey[1] as $key => $val){
    $data2 = get_page_code($val);
    preg_match($patternredirect, $data2 ,$url);
    echo $url[1];
}
```

The code is not actually relevant, the issue is when I run it the page doesn't show anything until the page is fully loaded. In my previous host the `echo` used to be shown while the code was being executed. Is it a way to change it and show things once got them and not to wait until every `$url[1]` is got? Thanks :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to flush output after each \`echo\` call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133209/how-to-flush-output-after-each-echo-call)

Answer (score 0):

Even if you flush the output, your browser may still simply refuse to display anything until the whole page is sent. A workaround is to create a JavaScript page that connects to the PHP server via a web socket, create a web socket server in PHP, then send the data in packets to the client and reconstruct it on the other end.

Comment: Then how's possible in my previous host with the exact code the content was shown once got it?

Comment: *may. The real answer is that I don't know (probably a default buffer size difference)... But some browsers will emulate this _anyway_, so you can't rely on the output buffering causing the user to be able to see the things live. Try the Python documentation's search tool to test this between browsers.